# Password: chsh: PAM: Authentication failure

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, docker, pam

Trying to run

```
RUN chsh -s /bin/bash www-data
```

(dockerfile) i tried to change it to /bin/zsh but still doesn't work. Docker file is too long, there is the offical repository with the file https://hub.docker.com/r/alexcheng/magento2/~/dockerfile/

Result :

```
  Password: chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
The command '/bin/sh -c chsh -s /bin/bash www-data' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

/etc/passwd

/etc/passwd

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/zsh
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/zsh
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:100:102:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
systemd-network:x:101:103:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd/netif:/bin/false
systemd-resolve:x:102:104:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd/resolve:/bin/false
systemd-bus-proxy:x:103:105:systemd Bus Proxy,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
syslog:x:104:108::/home/syslog:/bin/false
_apt:x:105:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false
messagebus:x:106:110::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
uuidd:x:107:111::/run/uuidd:/bin/false
lightdm:x:108:114:Light Display Manager:/var/lib/lightdm:/bin/false
whoopsie:x:109:117::/nonexistent:/bin/false
avahi-autoipd:x:110:119:Avahi autoip daemon,,,:/var/lib/avahi-autoipd:/bin/false
avahi:x:111:120:Avahi mDNS daemon,,,:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false
colord:x:112:123:colord colour management daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/bin/false
dnsmasq:x:113:65534:dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/misc:/bin/false
hplip:x:114:7:HPLIP system user,,,:/var/run/hplip:/bin/false
kernoops:x:115:65534:Kernel Oops Tracking Daemon,,,:/:/bin/false
pulse:x:116:124:PulseAudio daemon,,,:/var/run/pulse:/bin/false
rtkit:x:117:126:RealtimeKit,,,:/proc:/bin/false
saned:x:118:127::/var/lib/saned:/bin/false
usbmux:x:119:46:usbmux daemon,,,:/var/lib/usbmux:/bin/false
speech-dispatcher:x:120:29:Speech Dispatcher,,,:/var/run/speech-dispatcher:/bin/false
administrator:x:1000:1000:Administrator,,,:/home/administrator:/bin/bash
pkoz:x:1001:1001:Paul K,,,,:/home/pkoz:/usr/bin/zsh
guest-eaqooc:x:999:999:Guest:/tmp/guest-eaqooc:/bin/bash
sshd:x:121:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mysql:x:122:130:MySQL Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
```

/etc/pam.d/chsh

```
    # accounts with special shells from changing them.
auth       sufficient   pam_shells.so

# This allows root to change user shell without being
# prompted for a password
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add installing zsh to the `Dockerfile` before `RUN chsh -s..`? (`RUN apt install zsh` )

Also try commenting out `auth required pam_shells.so` in `/etc/pam.d/chsh`

see: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1224#issuecomment-31623113

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new Dockerfile, and add your customizations there.

```
FROM alexcheng/magento2:latest

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y zsh && \
    usermod -s /usr/bin/zsh www-data
```

Then to build it,

```
docker build -t alexcheng/magento2:latest-zsh .
```